# What is the way to quick-switch between tabs in Xcode 4

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, tabs, keyboard-shortcuts

I have opened many tabs while working on project. (new feature in Xcode 4).

But for switching from one tab to other tab, the only way I've found to do this is to use the mouse. Is there any way to switch between different tabs using keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: This still applies to Xcode 8 and most answers still work ok.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64848763/14531220 this is the right answer now.

Answer (score 321, accepted):

Shortcuts are:

- <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>}</kbd> - Select Next tab
- <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd> - Select Previous tab

Comment: That should be command + shift + ..., I think. At least on my machine.

Comment: ya it should be command + shift.. the command + } indents the line with a tab

Comment: The problem with the **Show Next Tab** and **Show Previous Tab** commands is that they don't work in a stack - so its left/right in the tab list and not "the last tab I was at". Is there a way to go back and forth through tab history?

Answer (score 98):

The default shortcuts are:

- <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd> - Select Next Tab
- <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>}</kbd> - Select Previous Tab

But I prefer going to `XCode -> Preferences -> Key bindings` and changing them to:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> - Select Next Tab
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> - Select Previous Tab

...so they work the same as in Chrome or Safari.

Comment: `CTRL` + `TAB` is much better and not used by default. Pity that we can't bind last used tab.

Comment: I think everybody should assume that people are generally used to browser ~ and use CTR + TAB / CTR + SHIFT + TAB  to change tabs.

Comment: 2nd one is beneficial :)

Comment: In Chrome it's also ALT-CMD-Left, so I changed it to that

Comment: I'm on Xcode 8.2.1 and couldn't find the mentioned bindings, they have been renamed to "*Show* Next/Previous Tab".

Comment: Looks like `CTRL` + `TAB` already works by default on Xcode 9.2.1

Answer (score 8):

If the shortcuts don't work (because of language, for example), you can define custom shortcut:

- XCode -> Preferences -> Key bindings
- Make sure that "all" is selected
- Define shortcuts for "Select Previous Tab" and "Select Next Tab"

I used <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>pageup</kbd> and <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>pagedown</kbd>, didn't generate any conflicts.

Comment: `cmd` + `pageup` is Move to Beginning of Document in Xcode 8 :-(

Answer (score 5):

XCode Windows menu option shows it as <kbd>⌘</kbd>+ <kbd>}</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+ <kbd>{</kbd> but I think it is a bug since <kbd>⌘</kbd>+ <kbd>{/}</kbd> is used for increase indent or decrease indent. 
The correct sequence is <kbd>⌘</kbd>+ <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>}</kbd> or <kbd>{</kbd>.

Comment: On my keyboard at least, { and } are shifted [ and ], so I think XCode is actually correct here, just not exactly clear. Personally I would have called it cmd+shift+[ and cmd+shift+]

Comment: That's exactly the reason. If you try it out in the Preferences pane you see that if you do `cmd+[` it will show that as the shortcut, while if you use `cmd+shift+[` it will show `cmd+{` as the shortcut.

Answer (score 5):

I perfer using BetterTouchTool to switch between tabs(include Chrome, Safari, Finder, Xcode, sublimeText and so on).

BetterTouchTool is a free software.

Just set `TipTap Left` and `TipTap Right` to `cmd+shift+{` and `cmd+shift+}`.

And than, you can use trackpads with tiptap to switch between taps.

Here is my configuration:[image]

Hope you will like it.

Comment: I love better touch tool. I think it's a great combo when used with XCode