# Xcode tab switch cmd+1 2 3

Tags: c++, xcode, tabs, key-bindings, switching

Im looking for a way to be able to switch tabs in Xcode not using next/previous tab but rather using modifier+1,2,3.. etc in order to get to a specific tab directly.

I have gotten a similiar problem solved for terminal.app with the help of this application/script
https://github.com/ciaran/terminaltabswitching
It's usable on ML, you only need to increase the MaxBundleVersion in info.plist.
It's used together with easySIMBL.

So I recently started using tabs in Xcode and this was the first thing i tried to find, as I prefer selecting tabs specifically.

Any idéas/solution? Thanks.

Comment: I use Xcode in hobby, and I can't recall this is even possible. The closest you'll come is next-prev switching, and a very good description (which you're probably already aware of) can be found in [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491023/what-is-the-way-to-quick-switch-between-tabs-in-xcode4)