# Shortcut for switching between tabs in Xcode now?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I need to set default behavior of the Xcode to switch between tabs.
I check out this [What is the way to quick-switch between tabs in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491023/what-is-the-way-to-quick-switch-between-tabs-in-xcode-4) but this is seeems to me old answer and when i try to set new shortcuts it is being conflict. Still is the same or something changed after Xcode12 switching between tabs in Xcode 12 now. ?

Comment: ⌘⇧[ - left, ⌘⇧] - right

Comment: thanks, it is working as well

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you right , the answer you share the link should be updated. Actually default one is coming with two options :

First one is most of developers prefers just like safari and chrome :

**ctrl + tab**   (select next tab)

**ctrl + tab + shift**  (select previous tab)

or

**command + shift + }**  (select next tab )

**command + shift +  {**  (select previous tab)

As I said both is coming default and you can use both. If you want to change this default settings then:

---

Press : **command + ,**   ( goes to Xcode preferences )

Ctrl + **tab ( 7 times )**    (or just click key bindings at 7th tab )

And make as you wish at this section